# Azure private registry for docker image

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, azure-container-registry

Below is my yaml file to create a container group with two containers names as fluentd and mapp.
But for the mapp container I want to get the image from a private repository. I am not using Azure Container Registry, I do not have an experience with it either.
I want to push the logs to Loganalytics.

```
apiVersion: 2019-12-01
location: eastus2
name: mycontainergroup003
properties:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer003
    properties:
      environmentVariables: []
      image: fluent/fluentd
      ports: []
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1.0
          memoryInGB: 1.5 
  - name: mapp-log 
    properties: 
    image: reg-dev.rx.com/gl/xg/iss/mapp/com.corp.mapp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT_latest
    resources:
      requests: 
        cpu: 1 
        memoryInGb: 1.5 
    ports:  
    - port: 80  
    - port: 8080 
    command:  - /bin/sh - -c  - >  i=0;  while true;  do  echo "$i: $(date)" >> /var/log/1.log;  echo "$(date) INFO $i" >> /var/log/2.log;  i=$((i+1));  sleep 1;  done 
  imageRegistryCredentials: 
  - server: reg-dev.rx.com 
    username: <username> 
    password: <password> 
  osType: Linux 
  restartPolicy: Always 
  diagnostics: 
    logAnalytics: 
      workspaceId: <id> 
      workspaceKey: <key> 
tags: null 
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

I am executing below command to run the yaml:

```
>az container create -g rg-np-tp-ip01-deployt-docker-test --name mycontainergroup003  --file .\azure-deploy-aci-2.yaml
(InaccessibleImage) The image 'reg-dev.rx.com/gl/xg/iss/mapp/com.corp.mapp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT_latest' in container group 'mycontainergroup003' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential.
Code: InaccessibleImage
Message: The image 'reg-dev.rx.com/gl/xg/iss/mapp/com.corp.mapp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT_latest' in container 
group 'mycontainergroup003' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential.
```

How can I make the imageregistry reg-dev.rx.com accessible from Azure. Till now, I used the same imageregistry in every yaml and ran 'kubectl apply' command. But now I am trying to run the yaml via Azure cli.
Can someone please help?

Comment: "az container" is for the Azure Container Instances service but you mention "kubectl apply" that is for Kubernetes. Can you clarify what is the Azure service you want to use?

Comment: What I meant is that I used 'kubectl apply ' for other yaml files which are AKS based, I used kubernetes level commands and in those cases I could access the image in path reg-dev.rx.com. But for this yaml file I am using az cli command and the same path reg-dev.rx.com is not accessible.

Comment: Try passing the parameters directly, just to see if it works without using an external file: az container create -g rg-np-tp-ip01-deployt-docker-test --name mycontainer003 --image reg-dev.rx.com/gl/xg/iss/mapp/com.corp.mapp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT_latest --cpu 1 --memory 1.5 --registry-login-server reg-dev.rx.com --registry-username <user> --registry-password <password> --ip-address Public --dns-name-label <aciDnsLabel> --ports 80  --command-line "/bin/sh - -c  - >  i=0;  while true;  do  echo '$i: $(date)' >> /var/log/1.log;  echo '$(date) INFO $i' >> /var/log/2.log;  i=$((i+1));  sleep 1;  done"

Comment: `nslookup reg-dev.rx.com 8.8.8.8` fails to resolve the hostname for me. How are you accessing it? Is this a private registry behind a firewall only known to your local DNS servers?

Comment: yes it`s a private registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error you are getting usually comes when you are giving wrong name and credentials for login server or Image that you are trying to pull.

I Can not tested as which private registry you are trying to use. But same thing can use achive using Azure Container registry. I tested in my environment and its working fine for me same you can apply in your environment as well.

**You can pushed your existing image into ACR using below command**

Example : you can apply like this below

Step 1 : **login in azure**

```
 az login
```

Step 2: **Created Container Registry**

```
az acr create -g "<resource group>" -n "TestMyAcr90" --sku Basic --admin-enabled true
```

.

Step 3 :**Tag docker image in the following format `loginserver/imagename`**

`docker tag 0e901e68141f testmyacr90.azurecr.io/my_nginx`
[image]

Step 4 : **login to ACR**.

`docker login testmyacr90.azurecr.io`

Step 5 : **Push docker images into container registry**

```
docker push testmyacr90.azurecr.io/my_nginx
```

[image]

**YAML FILE**

```
apiVersion: 2019-12-01
location: eastus2
name: mycontainergroup003
properties:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer003
    properties:
      environmentVariables: []
      image: fluent/fluentd
      ports: []
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1.0
          memoryInGB: 1.5
  - name: mapp-log
    properties:
      image: testmyacr90.azurecr.io/my_nginx:latest
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGb: 1.5
      ports:
      - port: 80
      - port: 8080
      command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - >
          i=0;
          while true;
          do
            echo "$i: $(date)" >> /var/log/1.log;
            echo "$(date) INFO $i" >> /var/log/2.log;
            i=$((i+1));
            sleep 1;
          done
  imageRegistryCredentials:
  - server: testmyacr90.azurecr.io
    username: TestMyAcr90
    password: SJ9I6XXXXXXXXXXXZXVSgaH
  osType: Linux
  restartPolicy: Always
  diagnostics:
    logAnalytics:
      workspaceId: dc742888-fd4d-474c-b23c-b9b69de70e02
      workspaceKey: ezG6IXXXXX_XXXXXXXVMsFOosAoR+1zrCDp9ltA==
tags: null
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

You can get the loginserver name , Username and password of ACR from here.

[image]

**Succesfully run the file and able to create Container Group along with two container as declare in file.**

[image]

[image]