# Coldfusion log parse in Azure Log Analytics Workspace

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances, azure-log-analytics-workspace, coldfusion-2021

I created an **Azure Container Instance** and **Coldfusion 2021** is running on it as a **Docker** image.

The application creates multiple log files. I sent all these logs to Standard Output by the symlink.

Now, I want to parse these logs file-wise in **Azure Log Analytics Workspace**.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Please check this thread which i have answered how to store logs of container in azure log analytics workspace , you just need to replace image as per your requirement : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72564294/azure-private-registry-for-docker-image/72602673#72602673

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT I already implemented that and custom logs are sent to ALAW. Now I want to parse each log separately. I am unable to do that.

Comment: Please check it might helps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/parse-text

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT I used Data Collector API for different log files and then parse those logs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-collector-api